# Displaying SVG as an ImageLayer - OpenLayers

Tags: svg, rendering, openlayers

As flagged in the following GitHub issues, OpenLayers do not display SVG images properly when referenced in an ImageLayer:

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4633

There was a solution to this implemented a few months ago, using the "render" property in the Layer class:
https://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer.html#~RenderFunction

But i cannot figure out how to implement this correctly. What is the frame state, and how can this be referenced correctly to the render property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devs behind OpenLayers have created an example to show how an SVG image can be rendered:

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/10363